# System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, invoke

It seems weird to me. All definitions match but it seems there is a problem with invoking a function with input `array<Object^>^` . Here is my brief code:

```
void WriteCOMPortPannel(array< String ^ >^ ){ \\ Do something};
delegate void WriteCOMPortDelegate(array< String ^ >^ );

array <String^ > ^COM_PORTS = this -> SerialPort ->GetPortNames();          
this->Invoke (gcnew WriteCOMPortDelegate(this, &MainForm::WriteCOMPortPannel), COM_PORTS);
```

In C# the solution is:

`this->Invoke (MyDeligate , New Object() COM_PORTS);.`

What about C++\CLI ? Is there any type mismatch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess The C++/CLI `Invoke` mistakes your `array< String^ >^` for the `array< Object^ >^` it expects to hold a parameter list.

You should try wrapping your `array< String^ >^` inside an `array< Object^ >^`.

```
array <String^ > ^COM_PORTS = this -> SerialPort ->GetPortNames();          
array <Object^ > ^parameters = gcnew array <Object^ >(1);
parameters[0] = COM_PORTS;
this->Invoke (gcnew WriteCOMPortDelegate(this, &MainForm::WriteCOMPortPannel), parameters);
```

Comment: For another question, why no error arisen when calling this -> SerialPort ->GetPortNames() in another thread ?
To put more information, I know SerialPort class doesn't support invoke !

Comment: The `SerialPort` class is not a control, so it's probably not single-thread-bound in the first place (meaning it doesn't *need* `Invoke`).

Comment: Thanks again! New topic for me to search.